# Next.js 14 Sitemap generation with multilanguage

Tags: next.js, multilingual, sitemap, app-router

My site on Next.js 14 (App Router) has multi-language support and needs to generate sitemap.xml with:

```
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="YOUR_LOCALE" href="YOUR_LINK" />
```

as Google shows in the following example:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/specialty/international/localized-versions#sitemap

How is it possible to do this?

In Next.js 14 (App Router) sitemap generation you can only specify 4 parameters that have nothing to do with localization:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/sitemap

Or you can write sitemap.xml manually, but the site has product pages that are more than 2000 and manually doing it is crazy.

Maybe there is a way to build a **string** yourself?
*(getServerSideProps - not supported in App Router)*